# Finding first day of calendar

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar

What i want to do is to create a simple calendar, and I want to find the first day of the first week of a specific month. My calendar is a Monday -> Sunday calendar and the following code works, but as you can see it's not that nice. Anyone have any better idea on how to get the first date in the calendar.

```
var now = new DateTime(Year, Month, 1);
now = now.AddDays(1-(int)now.DayOfWeek);
now = now.Day > 15 ? now : now.AddDays(-7);
```

The calendar will end up looking like this:

```
| <  |        Jan  2011       |  > |
------------------------------------
| Mo | Tu | We | Th | Fr | Sa | Su |
|[27]| 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 01 | 02 |
| 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 | 07 | 08 | 09 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| 31 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 |
```

And in this "image" it's  the [27] date that i'm trying to find.

**Solution (Found i better/cleaner to loop then calculate):**

```
    public DateTime FirstDay()
    {
        var date = new DateTime(Date.Year, Date.Month, 1);
        while (true)
        {
            if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
                return date;
            date = date.AddDays(-1);
        }
        return date;
    }

    public DateTime LastDay()
    {
        var date = new DateTime(Date.Year, Date.Month, 
                                DateTime.DaysInMonth(Date.Year, Date.Month));
        while (true)
        {
            if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                return date;
            date = date.AddDays(1);
        }
        return date;
    }
```

/BR
Andreas

Comment: +1 #wow, Actually i made a similar Calendar in a console app with C in my College.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would just do this. It is so easy to understand:

```
var firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
DateTime startOfCalendar = 
    FirstDayOfWeekOnOrBefore(
        firstDayOfMonth,
        DayOfWeek.Monday
    );

public static DateTime FirstDayOfWeekOnOrBefore(
    DateTime date,
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek
) {
    while(date.DayOfWeek != dayOfWeek) {
        date = date.AddDays(-1);
    }
    return date;
}
```

Additionally, if you want to change your calendar to start on something other than Monday, it's trivial now. A solution using modulo arithmetic would not be as maintainable.

Comment: why is this so complicated? much simpler solutions exist

Comment: @user492238 IMO this code is simpler than your (and my) solution. The loop terminates after a maximum of 7 iterations, so the performance is fine as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use modulo to calculate the number of filler days without a conditional statement:

```
DateTime firstOfMonth=new DateTime(year,month,1);
var weekDay=firstOfMonth.DayOfWeek;
int fillerDays=((int)weekDay+6)%7;
DateTime firstDayInCalendar=firstOfMonth.AddDays(-fillerDays);
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know it was possible to cast DayOfWeek to an int. I've always just seen it display the day string: "Monday".

Comment: @DougS It's an enum, and you can cast any enum to the underlying integral type.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this assuming first day ur referring to is Monday

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2011, 2, 2);
Console.WriteLine(dt.AddDays((8 - (int)dt.DayOfWeek) % 7));
```

Comment: But why? It's not immediately comprehensible. There is clearer code that can be immediately grasped. You'll appreciate writing it in three months when you need to maintain something, or heaven forbid, fix a nasty bug in it because it's so unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I do not like while loops, because they are expensive when used with LINQ 
Hope someone else can reuse this code: (if you are in the USA, then just remove [ + 6) % 7)] in two lines)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Expands the month.
    /// | <  |        Jan  2011       |  > |
    /// ------------------------------------
    /// | Mo | Tu | We | Th | Fr | Sa | Su |
    /// |[27]| 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 01 | 02 |
    /// | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 | 07 | 08 | 09 |
    /// | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
    /// | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
    /// | 31 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 |
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start">Some day in the month of interest, the start date is updated to become the date of firstDayInCalendar</param>
    /// <returns>The number of days to show. This value is either (28, 35 or 42)</returns>
    public static int ExpandMonth(ref DateTime start)
    {
        DateTime first = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month, 1);
        DateTime last = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(start.Year, start.Month));
        start = first.AddDays(-((int)first.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7);
        last = last.AddDays(7 - ((int)last.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7);
        return last.Subtract(start).Days;
    }
```

//Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I found myself needing to do this quite often, so I created the following extension method.

```
public static DateTime FirstDateOfCalendarMonth(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday)
{
  dt = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1);
  while (dt.DayOfWeek != firstDayOfWeek){
    dt = dt.AddDays(-1);
  }
  return dt;
}
```

Use it like this

```
var firstCalDate = DateTime.Now.FirstDateOfCalendarMonth();
```

It defaults to Sunday as the first DayOfWeek, but you can pass it whatever DayOfWeek you like,  like this:

```
var firstCalDate = DateTime.Now.FirstDateOfCalendarMonth(DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime start_date = Cal_start_date.SelectedDate;
DateTime end_date = Cal_end_date.SelectedDate;

Dictionary<string, int> dic_week_day = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dic_week_day["Sunday"] = 1;
dic_week_day["Monday"] = 2;
dic_week_day["Tuesday"] = 3;
dic_week_day["Wednesday"] = 4;
dic_week_day["Thursday"] = 5;
dic_week_day["Friday"] = 6;
dic_week_day["Saturday"] = 7;

DateTime first_day = start_date.AddDays(1 - start_date.Day);
int selected_day = dic_week_day[Drp_day_of_week.SelectedValue.ToString()];

string str_html = "";
for (DateTime i = first_day; i <= end_date; i = i.AddMonths(1))
{
    int day_of_week = dic_week_day[i.DayOfWeek.ToString()];
    DateTime temp_date;
    if (day_of_week > selected_day)
    {
        temp_date = i.AddDays((7 - day_of_week) + selected_day);
    }
    else
    {
        temp_date = i.AddDays(selected_day - day_of_week);
    }

    DateTime last_day_of_month = (temp_date.AddMonths(1)).AddDays(-temp_date.Day);

    if (Drp_occurrence.SelectedValue.ToString() == "odd")
    {
        if (start_date <= temp_date && temp_date <= end_date && temp_date <= last_day_of_month)
        {
            str_html += "<br />" + temp_date.ToString();
        }

        DateTime res_date = temp_date.AddDays(14);

        if (start_date <= res_date && res_date <= end_date && res_date <= last_day_of_month)
        {
            str_html += "  ,  " + res_date.ToString();
        }

        res_date = temp_date.AddDays(28);

        if (start_date <= res_date && res_date <= end_date && res_date <= last_day_of_month)
        {
            str_html += "  ,  " + res_date.ToString();
        }
    }
    else if (Drp_occurrence.SelectedValue.ToString() == "even")
    {
        DateTime res_date = temp_date.AddDays(7);

        if (start_date <= res_date && res_date <= end_date && res_date <= last_day_of_month)
        {
            str_html += "<br />" + res_date.ToString();
        }

        res_date = temp_date.AddDays(21);

        if (start_date <= res_date && res_date <= end_date && res_date <= last_day_of_month)
        {
            str_html += "  ,  " + res_date.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int occurrence = Int32.Parse(Drp_occurrence.SelectedValue.ToString());

        DateTime res_date = temp_date.AddDays((occurrence - 1) * 7);

        if (start_date <= res_date && res_date <= end_date && res_date <= last_day_of_month)
        {
            str_html += "<br />" + res_date.ToString();
        }
    }
}

Div_result.InnerHtml = str_html;
```

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: Following code has a bug! Use modulo arithmetic, to compensate the circumstance, .NET begins the week on sunday! See other solutions here (without the one with an extra function).

If you need to find the "27" (i.e. the first day for the display of a month) simply use this:

```
DateTime monthStart = new DateTime(year, month, 1); 
DateTime monthDisplayStart = monthStart.AddDays(-((int)monthStart.DayOfWeek - 1));
```

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but I suspect that your code doesn't work for for one possible weekday because .net sees Sunday as first day of the week, and the OP Monday.

Comment: This code has a bug, its meaning isn't immediately obvious, and it's not maintainable.

Comment: @Jason what you mean with "maintainable" here? Why should this be 'maintainable' in any way? Its not a good coding practice in general to prepare for *every* possible change request, which might come up in the future. So code like this should simply work and than left alone.

Comment: @user492238: But that's not what "maintainable" means. "Maintainable" does not mean preparing for every possible change request. Instead, it means coding a way that is easy to correct defects and meet future requirements. It doesn't mean trying to anticipate future requests and coding to them, but rather coding in a way that meeting future requests is easier. One characteristic of maintainable code is readability. Code that is easier to understand is easier to maintain.