# Get 1st of current month and year

Tags: c#, datetime

How do I get the first of the current Month and Year into a DateTime variable?

I can get the current date by saying:

> FromDate = DateTime.Today;

I've been playing arround with trying to set the `Day` parameter of `Today` and getting the `Month` and `Year` parameters for `Today` to create a new `DateTime`, but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [set DateTime to start of month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002556/set-datetime-to-start-of-month)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [DateTime Constructor (Int32, Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor, which expects, year, month and day, You can use the current date year and month and explicitly pass `1` as the `Day` part like:

```
DateTime startOfCurrentMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 
                                            DateTime.Today.Month, 
                                            1);
```

You can cache the value of `DateTime.Today` in a variable and use that in your constructor call, instead of getting `DateTime.Today` for year and month.

Answer (score 3):

Set a variable like:

```
DateTime now = System.DateTime.Now;
```

and then use it to create what you are looking for:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
```